# Uneven spaces between multiline navigation links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, multiline

I'm new so don't mind if I ask some pretty dumb questions, I've been trying to create a navigation menu that has links that pop up once the mouse hovers over, it's been great so far, the only problem I have is that the spaces between the links appear to be uneven.

Now I've searched high and low (I'm bad with google) for an answer but just can't seem to find one.
I've tried the following CSS.

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
```

TL:DR; space between an unorganised row of vertical multiline links is uneven.

Here's the http://jsfiddle.net/1f9b0h6p/ , help please? ;-;

Best regards,
Vernon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unwanted `line-height` from the ids `#top, #top li li, #top li li a` and `height` from the id `#top li:hover li`

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1f9b0h6p/3/)

Answer (score 1):

In `#top li:hover li{` change the `height` from `33px` to `auto`. here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1f9b0h6p/2/)